# On double series involving Gregory coefficients and quotients of particular values of the gamma function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Edited, there was a mistake.** I've edited because there was a mistake, advertised from the answerer, I hope that now all is right.

Yesterday I got (but I haven't tested it numerically) that
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{|G_n|}{k}\frac{\Gamma(n+k+\frac{1}{2})}{(n+k+1)!}=\frac{\pi(-5+8\log 2)}{8},$$
where $G_n$ denotes the sequence of Gregory coefficients or reciprocal logarithmic numbers, see the Wikipedia [*Gregory coefficients*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients). Using the generating function for this sequence and the result of the Problem 4383 from Crux Mathematicorum ([1]), I can then write the closed-form of a series of the type

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty(\text{a function of }G_n\text{, or }|G_n|,\text{ and }k)\cdot(\text{particular values of the gamma function}).$$

> **Question.** Are known series of previous type and how are evaluated? If it is in the literature refer it, and I try to search and read those statements from the literature. In other case, what work can be done to deduce similar formulas to get the closed-form for double series of the previous type? **Many thanks.**

Here I add my example of series, how I got the result for the series of the first paragraph.

**Example.** All issues of convergence are satisfied by uniform convergence of the series in the unit interval. Multiplying the Maclaurin series of the Gregory coefficients, specialized for $1-x$, by $\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}}$ and integrating the equation over the unit interval, one gets invoking the Problem 4383, due to Michel Bataille, that $$-\sum_{n=1}^\infty |G_n|\left(\int_0^1(\log (1-x))\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}}x^n dx\right)=\frac{\pi(-5+8\log 2)}{8}.\tag{1}$$
We make a change of varialbe use the Taylor series of the logarithm to state that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{|G_n|}{k}\left(\int_0^1 z^{n+k} \sqrt{\frac{1-z}{z}}dz\right)=\frac{\pi(-5+8\log 2)}{8},\tag{2}$$
and finally I've used Wolfram Alpha online calculator (it is the definition of the gamma function) to get a closed-form of the integral in terms of particular values of the gamma function.

### References:

[1] *Problem 4383*, Crux Mathematicorum, Volume 45, Number 6, July 2019.

Comment: The web page of Crux Mathematicorum (I believe that is a journal of the Canadian Mathematical Society) is https://cms.math.ca/crux/ from which you can see its Digital Archive.

Answer (score 1):

The result in the OP

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{G_n}{k}\frac{\Gamma(k+\frac{3}{2})\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})}{(n+k+1)!}=\frac{\pi(1-8\log 2)}{8}=-1.78489,$$
does not seem to agree with a numerical estimate of the series. I first evaluated the sum over $k$, which has a closed form expression, 
$$\sigma_n=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\Gamma \left(k+\frac{3}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{k (k+n+1)!}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\, \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(\psi ^{(0)}(n+2)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)}{2 \Gamma (n+2)},$$
with $\psi^{(0)}$ the polygamma function, and then evaluated
$$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N G_n \sigma_n,$$
using the following Mathematica code for the Gregory coefficients:

`g[n_] := Integrate[x*Pochhammer[x - n + 1, n - 1]/n!, {x, 0, 1}]`

The plot below of $S_N$ versus $N$ (evaluated for $N$ up to 20) suggests convergence to 0.16653, far from the result in the OP.

[image]

---

new version: the OP has a new series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{|G_n|}{k}\frac{\Gamma(k+\frac{3}{2})\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})}{(n+k+1)!}=\frac{\pi(-5+8\log 2)}{8}=0.214091,$$

which I have also evaluated numerically and seems to converge to 0.1866.

[image]

Comment: Many thnanks I am going to check my calculations in next few hours.

Comment: I've added a new expression, many thanks and I'm sorry.

Comment: My new expression involves the absolute value of the Gregory coefficients, that is $|G_n|$, thus  I don't know if my second proposal is true or false.

Comment: This is my new expression, I hope that now it is right.

Comment: Then if possible please delete your answer, with the purpose to delete my own bad post. Many thanks.

Comment: no damage is made by retaining the post, perhaps someone will be motivated to fix it.